# Starring a repository with the github API

Tags: github, put, github-api

I'm trying to star a repository using the GithubAPI. This is done via a [PUT request to `/user/starred/:owner/:repo`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository). I attempted to implement this feature in python using the requests library, but it isn't working. Here is a minimum working example:

The constant are defined as `GITHUB_API = api.github.com`, `GITHUB_USER = the username of the owner of the repo to be starred`, and `GITHUB_REPO = the name of the repo to be starred`

```
url = urljoin(GITHUB_API, (user + '/starred/' + GITHUB_USER + '/' + GITHUB_REPO))
r = requests.put(url,auth=(user,password))
print r.text
```

This code results in an error that reads:

```
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

I think that I'm missing something fundamental about the process of issuing a PUT request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the parameters you pass to [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin). The first parameter is supposed to be an absolute URL, while the second parameter is a relative URL. `urljoin()` then creates an absolute URL from that.

Also, "user" in this case is supposed to be a literal part of the URL, and not the username.

In this case, I would forgo the `urljoin()`-function completely, and instead use simple string substitution:

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/user/starred/{owner}/{repo}'.format(
          owner=GITHUB_USER,
          repo=GITHUB_REPO
      )
```

Comment: Literally cannot upvote hard enough. This is the correct answer, but I'm not sure I can mark it yet.